# How to preview first person animation in UE5 Editor?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I'm making FPS game with Unreal Engine 5.3.
I want to preview player arm animations in first person View.

But I can't find how to snap a camera into a bone or certain transform in Animation Editor.

How to locate camera in animation editor as same location as Game View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is that you cannot. Unreal Engine does not provide this capability in the Editor itself.

However, you can easily work around this by placing your Actor in a level, hitting play, and then making modifications to the animation. PIE (Play In Editor) *does* support hot-reload of Animations and Animation Blueprints so you can preview your animation changes in-game in real-time with animation sequences and compile (while game is running) for the Animation Blueprint.